# c++ rapidjson addMember & rapidxml

Tags: c++, casting, rapidjson, rapidxml

When I use the function AddMember from the c++ library RapidJson and I use string as parameters

Everything Work fine

```
jsvalue.AddMember("Fare", "0", allocator);
```

but when I try to use a Function of RapidXml as parameter to get the node name, I get a fatal error

```
std::cout << "name : " << xmlnode_chd->name() << " value : " << xmlnode_chd->first_node()->value() << std::endl;
jsvalue.AddMember(std::string(xmlnode_chd->name()), std::string(xmlnode_chd->first_node()->value()), allocator);
```

xmlnode_chd->name() return a char*, that's why I cast it to string

This is the error message I get :

/home/otf/test/./include/xml2json.hpp|210|error: no matching function for call to ‘rapidjson::GenericValue >::AddMember(std::string, std::string, rapidjson::GenericDocument >::AllocatorType&)’|

Answer (score 2):

The rapidjson library's GenericValue::AddMember method does not contain an overload that accepts a std::basic_string as its first parameter. Your choices are GenericValue (which must be a string itself) or GenericStringRef. GenericStringRef can be constructed from a const char*, which is why your initial method worked, but cannot be constructed via a std::string directly. I recommend you rewrite your code to:

```
jsvalue.AddMember(xmlnode_chd->name(), xmlnode_chd->first_node()->value(), allocator);
```

BTW, you can find the documentation on this [here](http://rapidjson.org/classrapidjson_1_1_generic_value-members.html)